Manually adding citation of my work on Google Scholar
I recently noticed that my work was cited in a working paper uploaded to arXiv about five months ago. However, the citation format is incorrect (wrong year, missing repository), and it has not been reflected in my Google Scholar citation count.
I have already contacted the authors of the arXiv paper to request a correction in their next version. In the meantime, I am wondering if it is possible to manually add this citation to my Google Scholar count.
